# How do I make the useEffect activate when the "Analyze Weather" button is clicked (react.js)

Tags: reactjs

I want the useEffect to happen only when the button "Analyze Weather" is clicked, how do i do that ?

This is my code

```
const PredictBestPage = () => {

    const [latitude , setLatitiude] = useState('')
    const [longitude , setLongitude] = useState('')

    const [isAnalyzing , setIsAnalyzing] = useState(false)

    const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?'
    const API_KEY = //The Api Key(I cannot show this) 

    useEffect(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((postion) => {
            setLatitiude(postion.coords.latitude)
            setLongitude(postion.coords.longitude)
        })

        axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    }, [])

    const analyzeWeather = () => {
        if(latitude === "" || longitude === "") {
            <ErrorPrediction />
        }

        setIsAnalyzing(true)

    }

    

  return (
    <>
        <Navbar />
         {
            isAnalyzing 
            ?
            <div className = {styles.loader}>
                <Loader />
            </div>
            
            :
            <div className= {styles.predictMainCont}>
            <div className= {styles.analyzeBtn} onClick= {analyzeWeather}>
                Analyze Weather Conditions
            </div>
        </div>
         }
        
    </>
  )
}

export default PredictBestPage
```

So basically i want it that when i click the Analyze Weather button which has the onclick of function analyzeWeather the useEffect should fire off. How do i do that? I am a beginner at this, thank you for the assist in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add your useState variable in the useEffect**

```
useEffect(() => {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((postion) => {
                setLatitiude(postion.coords.latitude)
                setLongitude(postion.coords.longitude)
            })
    
        axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    }, [isAnalyzing])
```

Adding `isAnalyzing` in the UseEffect will run the code when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Your current useEffect will works just one time which is after mounting your component. If you want to run it again with changing of  *isAnalyzing* state, you must add it to dependency array of useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {

    // Callback function

}, [dependency array])
```

So, your useEffect hook must be :

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((postion) => {
        setLatitiude(postion.coords.latitude)
        setLongitude(postion.coords.longitude)
    })
 axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=${API_KEY}`)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
    })
}, [isAnalyzing])
```

But, There is an important fact: Your useEffect will be invoked once withouth any click.

If you don't want this, You can simply use a regular function to call data with api. It depends on your buisiness logic.